# how to load an rsa asymmetric key pair with obj-c on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security

I have the raw bytes of public and private key in a buffer and want to use that information to encrypt / decrypt data.

I do know that I could generate a keypair using `SecKeyGeneratePair` and then save it to the keychain, but i don't want that...

essentially, i need the Objective-C equivalent of the following Java Code (using Bouncycastle)

```
BigInteger modulus = ....
BigInteger publicExponent = ....
BigInteger privateExponent = ....

RSAKeyParameters pubKey = new RSAKeyParameters(false, modulus, publicExponent);
RSAKeyParameters privKey = new RSAKeyParameters(true, modulus, privateExponent);

return new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(pubKey, privKey);
```

Any ideas? I'm really stuck on that problem....

Comment: Have you solve this problem. I am also having same issue please help me if you have solution for this please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: no, i'll to this with openssl-based code (which i already use for win / linux)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know that OpenSSL allows you to do this, so you might want to investigate compiling OpenSSL into your project...

[This link](http://www.therareair.com/2009/01/01/tutorial-how-to-compile-openssl-for-the-iphone/) looks like it has decent instructions on how to do that.